# Assign value to member of struct using double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

I have a function that takes a double pointer to a struct and assigns a value. However I get an "access violation writing location ..." when trying to access the member `member1`.
This is my code:

```
struct mystruct{
  unsigned int member1;
  void * data;
};

int main(){

  mystruct **foo = new mystruct *;
  bar(foo);

}

void bar(unsigned int val, mystruct ** foo)
{
    (*foo)->member1 = val;
}
```

Comment: Forget `**` in C++, trust me you will not lose anything.

Comment: Note: I changed the C tag to C++ as he was using `new` but maybe he want's C code and jsut isn't knowing new is not part of C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just created a new mystruct pointer. That means:

You get allocated a memory block, large enough to hold a address, and assign it to the pointer which is pointing to a pointer that points to a `mystruct` member.
That doesn't mean, that there is a valid address hold in the pointer which you expect to be pointing to a `mystruct` element. Even more currently there isn't even a valid address, where the pointer to the pointer is pointing on, as you just assigned a valid memory area to it, what doesn't mean there is a usefull address stored in.

So at all, what you want is:

You want a pointer which has a valid memory block to store a address in of another pointer, which is pointing to a valid memory area, where is a (probably valid) `mystruct` stored in.

What you are doing is: you are requesting a memory area where you COULD (what you aren't even doing) store a poitner to another pointer... and so on.

so what you should do is:

```
mystruct **foo = new mystruct *;
*foo = new mystruct;
```

Answer (score 4):

> I have a function that takes a double pointer

That's weird. If you can, simplify it to take a reference:

```
void bar(unsigned int val, mystruct & foo) {
    foo.member1 = val;
}

mystruct foo;
bar(42, foo);
```

If you don't have control over the function, then you'll need an object at the end of the pointer trail:

```
mystruct foo;
mystruct * pointless = &foo;
bar(42, &pointless);
```

You can, of course, mess around with `new` if you really want to; but that's almost certainly a bad idea.

Your code allocates and leaks a pointer, but doesn't initialise it to point to a valid object; so dereferencing it gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

This C-style function:

```
void bar1(mystruct* foo) {
    foo->member1 = val;
}
```

takes an argument of type `mystruct*` in order for *changes made to object* that `foo` points to to be *visible to the caller*. However this function:

```
void bar(unsigned int val, mystruct ** foo) {
    (*foo)->member1 = val;
}
```

takes pointer to `mystruct*` (most likely) in order to to *modify the pointer itself*, i.e. in order for *changes made to the pointer* to be visible to the caller and thus probably meant to be used this way:

```
mystruct* foo = new mystruct;
bar(&foo);
```

... yet usually it is reasonable to avoid dynamic allocation and passing pointers should be rather rarity than a common practice. Prefer objects with automatic storage duration over the dynamically allocated ones and prefer passing by reference over passing by pointer (when possible).

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good advice. But also, if you have control over the `bar` function, and need to be able to change in `bar` to what object your `mystruct *` pointer points to (which is probably the reason why you have a double pointer in the first place), then the cleanest approach is to use the following signature for `bar`:

```
void bar(unsigned int val, mystruct * &foo);
```

It passes by reference a pointer, so you are able to change to what object the pointer points to, without sacrificing readability of the code, for instance:

```
int main()
{
    mystruct * foo = new mystruct;
    bar(42, foo);
}

void bar(unsigned int val, mystruct * &foo)
{ 
    foo->member1 = val;
    foo = new mystruct;
}
```

A complete usage scenario without memory leak could be:

```
int main()
{
    // allocate dynamically a mystruct whose member1 is equal to 1.
    mystruct * foo1 = new mystruct;
    mystruct * foo2 = foo1;
    foo1->member1 = 1;

    // pass by reference foo1
    bar(42, foo1);
    // here, foo1->member1 == 42 and foo2->member1 == 10

    // free memory
    delete foo1; // the one allocated in bar()
    delete foo2; // the one allocated in main()
}

void bar(unsigned int val, mystruct * &foo)
{ 
    // modify the object allocated in main()
    foo->member1 = 10;

    // allocate dynamically a mystruct, store its address in foo
    foo = new mystruct; 
    foo->member1 = val; 
}
```

Comment: My answer also fits that way it just doesn't do it by reference, more it does it the way, the OP mentioned it. but anyway +1 for you.

Comment: Yes, your answer is my favourite with Liho's one, I already +1'ed them, but since it is good practice to pass by reference whenever possible, I figured it was useful to tell the OP how to do in this case ;-)

Comment: @Zaibis But you were right on one point, I changed "the correct approach" by "the cleanest approach". All are correct ;-)